# Using a form for parameter on Query in Access 2007

Tags: forms, parameters, ms-access-2007

I am very new to Access 2007 and i am trying to use a form with a combobox to enter a parameter in a query without success.

I have tried to link the form and query by entering the following in the Criteria section of the query:

[Forms]![RunStatusReport]![ProjectName]  where RunStatusReport is the form name and ProjectName is the field on the form.  i also have a button on the form that opens the query.

Also

i have tried a bit of VBA

Private Sub ProjectName_AfterUpdate()
End Sub

Public Function GetCutoff()
GetCutoff = Form_RunStatusReport.ProjectName.Value

End Function

Neither returns the record from the combobox to the query.
the Query just runs and returns a blank table.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried to create the parameter in the query designer? By doing this all you need to do then is run the query and an input box will appear asking for your parameter. You could then just create a form with a button that runs the query.

Comment: Cheers for your help Matt I think I have figured it out

Comment: No problem, I have posted as an answer if you don't mind ticking it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the parameter in the query designer, then you need to do then is run the query and an input box will appear asking for your parameter. You could then just create a form with a button that runs the query.